# Get-AzDenyAssignment: 'directoryObjectId' cannot be null

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to list the deny statements in my azure subscription as per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/deny-assignments-powershell), however, I'm getting this error:

```
PS /Users/me> Get-AzDenyAssignment
WARNING: We have migrated the API calls for this cmdlet from Azure Active Directory Graph to Microsoft Graph.
Visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2181475 for any permission issues.
Get-AzDenyAssignment: 'directoryObjectId' cannot be null.
```

The page listed in the output does not have any information on directoryObjectId.

I've also tried other combinations, e.g.

```
PS /Users/me> Get-AzDenyAssignment -ResourceGroupName my-resource-group
WARNING: We have migrated the API calls for this cmdlet from Azure Active Directory Graph to Microsoft Graph.
Visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2181475 for any permission issues.
Get-AzDenyAssignment: 'directoryObjectId' cannot be null.
```

Any ideas?

---

My environment:

```
PS /Users/chris.snow> Get-Module

ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                ----------------
Script     2.9.0                 Az.Accounts                         {Add-AzEnvironment, Clear-AzConfig, Clear-AzCont…
Script     6.0.1                 Az.Resources                        {Export-AzResourceGroup, Export-AzTemplateSpec, …
Script     1.10.0                Microsoft.Graph.Authentication      {Add-MgEnvironment, Connect-MgGraph, Disconnect-…
Script     1.10.0                Microsoft.Graph.DirectoryObjects    {Confirm-MgDirectoryObjectMemberGroup, Confirm-M…
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Content, Clear-Content, Clear-Item, Clear-I…
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-O…
Script     1.4.7                 PackageManagement                   {Find-Package, Find-PackageProvider, Get-Package…
Script     2.2.5                 PowerShellGet                       {Find-Command, Find-DscResource, Find-Module, Fi…
Script     2.1.0                 PSReadLine                          {Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadLineOption,…
```

Comment: What is your RBAC role in Azure Subscription ?

Comment: It looks like it is `RoleDefinitionName : Contributor` in pwsh.  I also see `Global administrator` in AD

Comment: Even I have a `Contributor` Role. Iam able to run the cmd without any issues ![Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4SbO.png)

Comment: As mentioned in the [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/deny-assignments-powershell#prerequisites) section in the doc which you have provided, You must have a Contributor/Owner / Reader / User Access Administrator in Azure Subscription

Comment: Please check your role in Azure subscription

Answer (score 1):

- We can check the list of deny statements of azure subscription  in ***Azure Portal*** or in ***Azure CLI*** or by using ***REST API***
- Before checking the list please make sure that you have the required permissions as mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles)

### Checking the role in Azure Portal

Open ***Azure Portal*** => ***Subscriptions*** => Select ***your Subscription*** =>***Access Control (IAM)*** => ***Check Access*** => ***View my access***
[image]

### View from  Azure Portal

Navigate to the ***Azure Portal*** => ***Subscriptions*** => Select ***your Subscription*** =>***Access Control (IAM)*** => Click on ***View Deny Assignments*** tab

[image]

### Using Azure CLI

```cs
Get-AzDenyAssignment
```

[image]

### Using REST API

```cs
GET https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/denyAssignments/{deny-assignment-id}?api-version=2018-07-01-preview
```

- Scope - I have given `Subscriptions/ "MySubscriptionID"`

[image]